# Creating a Todo list in ReactJS, using mapping component struggling with mapping data.(Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new in ReactJS , was just trying to create Todo list using various method.
Presently , i am struggling in mapping components , my const Tododata shows tonnes of errors.

Here is the snippet:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlG04.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need an array instead of object for tododata. Please check the following code snippet.

```
const Tododata = [
    {
        id: 3,
        ext: 'to take a shower',
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        ext: 'to brush teeth',
        completed: true
    },
    ...
];
```